# A Random Line Intersecting the Corner of a Square on an Infinite Grid of Squares

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I thought that I could consider the grid as the analytic plane and the corners as $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the line as $y = mx + n$ for any arbitrary pair of $m$ and $n$. Then if $m$ is rational, the line would intersect infinitely many corners, otherwise it would at most intersect once. I have two questions. First, is my reasoning correct? Second, is a pure geometrical solution possible without using the properties of numbers and considering corners as points on a coordinate system?

Comment: I assume you meant "an arbitrary [...] $n$" instead of $y$. In that case, no. Once you've picked $m$ (or $n$) the other parameter can be deduced from the "corner" $(x,y)$ through which the line goes through. A rational $m$ will then yield infinitely many "corners" on that line. I don't get your second question.

Comment: @N.Bach yes I meant arbitrary $n$ I fixed it now. For the second question, what I am trying to say is if it's possible to come to the same conclusion without having to use $y = mx+n$ and the Cartesian Coordinates. (like if Euclid or Archimedes tackled the same question what kind of approach would he take?)